# Web3 estimateGas error: gas required exceeds allowance?

Tags: web3js, web3.py

I would like to estimate the amount of gas required for a transaction before actually sending it with web3. For some reason I always get a gas exceeded error. I've double-checked my solidity code and there are no errors failing during this function call. Does anyone know why `estimateGas()` does not work for my use case?

My Code:

```
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider

web3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/{LONG_INFURA_PROJECT_ID}'))

abi = [ ... long abi ...]
MyContract = web3.eth.contract(address="[contract_address]", abi=abi)

# this line fails...
# note: contractMethod is the name of the contract function I'm trying to call
estimated_gas = MyContract.functions.contractMethod("some_param").estimateGas()
```

Once I try to execute the line where `estimateGas()` is called, I get the following error:

```
{'code': -32000, 'message': 'gas required exceeds allowance (124572510) or always failing transaction'}
```

Comment: What is `contractMethod`?

Comment: @goodvibration `contractMethod` is a placeholder name for the name of the function I am calling on the contract `MyContract`

Comment: And how exactly do you expect anyone to be able to answer your question without seeing the code of that function???

Comment: @goodvibration I have been able to make the methodCall successfully when I send the transaction. As a result, I deduced that the error message created when I attempt to `estimateGas()` is independent of the function call. I get this error no matter what method I try to invoke on the function. I am fairly new to ethereum dev, so I apologize if the information I've included in the question is not sufficient for help or different than you require/expect. I can update this if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I need to pass a `transaction` to the `estimateGas()` function. In addition, I [needed to delete the `data` and `to` fields from the transaction](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py/blob/master/web3/contract.py#L1013) dictionary (if they exist).

Final Working Code:

```
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider

web3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/{LONG_INFURA_PROJECT_ID}'))

# grab contract instance using web3
abi = [ ... long abi ...]
MyContract = web3.eth.contract(address="[contract_address]", abi=abi)

# get nonce to use for transaction
nonce = web3.eth.getTransactionCount("<YOUR_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS>")

# create the transaction
transaction = Controller.functions \
            .doHardWork(*params) \
            .buildTransaction({
                'gas': 2000000,
                'gasPrice': web3.toWei(100),
                'from': "<YOUR_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS>",
                'nonce': nonce
            }) 

# delete the data and to fields from the transaction
del transaction['data']
del transaction['to']

# calculate gas
estimated_gas = MyContract.functions.contractMethod("some_param").estimateGas()
```